# Can we deduce that Majorana fermions are neutral from their commutation relations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, charge, dirac-equation, majorana-fermions

Let $\psi$ be a Majorana field, then it obeys the reality condition that it is equal to its charge conjugate. In components, this reads

$$ \psi_i = C_{ij} \psi_j^\dagger $$

where $\psi_i$ are the components of the field and $C_{ij}$ are the components of the unitary charge conjugation matrix. The Majorana field obeys the equal time commutation relations

$$ \{ \psi_i(t,\mathbf{x}),\psi^\dagger_j(t,\mathbf{y})\}=\delta_{ij}\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}) 
\\
\{ \psi_i(t,\mathbf{x}),\psi_j(t,\mathbf{y}) \}=C_{ij}\delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$$

Cf. Eq. (18) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1001.2760). I was wondering whether we can deduce that a Majorana field is electrically neutral just from these commutation relations. The electric charge is defined as $\rho = \psi^\dagger \psi$, which when expanded out gives

$$ \rho(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i}\psi_i^\dagger(\mathbf{x}) \psi_i(\mathbf{x}) =  \sum_{ij} \psi_i^\dagger(\mathbf{x})C_{ij} \psi_j^\dagger(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{ij} C_{ij} \left( \{ \psi_i^\dagger(\mathbf{x}),\psi_j^\dagger(\mathbf{x})\} -\psi_j^\dagger(\mathbf{x})\psi^\dagger_i(\mathbf{x}) \right) = -\rho(\mathbf{x})+ \sum_{ij} C_{ij}C_{ij}^* \delta(0) \\ = -\rho(\mathbf{x}) + 4\delta(0) $$

Where I have used the fact that $C$ is symmetric and unitary (for example, in the chiral representation $C = \sigma^y \otimes \sigma^y$). Therefore, $\rho(\mathbf{x}) = 2\delta(0)$ which is not zero. What is going on?

If we worked at the classical level and assumed these were anti-commuting Grassman numbers, then this would be equal to zero. However, when upgraded to a quantum field, the anti-commutation relations are slightly different and depend on the coordinates. I was thinking maybe normal ordering would remove this infinity, however everything is already in normal order.

Comment: Why do you say that $\rho(x)$ is already normal-ordered? What are you assuming the operators $\psi$ do to the vacuum state?

Comment: Well $\psi^\dagger \psi$ has all the creation operators on the left, however maybe I am wrong to use this for position space modes? I have not assumed what $\psi$ does to the vacuum.

Comment: I'm questioning the assumption that $\psi^\dagger\psi$ has all creation operators on the left. Doesn't the field $\psi$ itself contain both creation and annihilation operators? This is already true for a free Dirac spinor field, and it must be true also for a free Majorana spinor field where the $\psi^\dagger_n$ are linear combinations of the $\psi_n$. (If the fields aren't free, then determining which operators are creation/annihilation operators [aka energy raising/lowering operators] can be prohibitively difficult.)